# Slow query in MySQL - dictionary database

Tags: mysql, regex

My question is long (sorry for that) and it requires some explanations.

I have a big MySQL database which stands for a full Romanian dictionary with word definitions. The definition table is having ~180.000 records.

I use this database to return definitions on a website. One of the functionality is to search within the definition. meaning: show all the definitions that contain all the different words of the query. In Romanian, there are a lot of flexional forms for a word (nouns, articles, verbs) depending on case, tense etc. For example, the word **casa** (which means house) can be **casei** in Dative, or case in Nominative plural, **caselor** in Dative plural etc. I want the definitions to include all these forms.

I managed to create the query, but it runs really slow. I tried both with regexp and with like clauses, and I choose the one with like clause because it was quicker (10 secs vs 35 secs with regexp).

I tried to full text index the table, but it didn't decrease the query run time.

My query for three words (**apa**, **cascada**, **munte**) is:

```
SELECT htmlRep from 
    (SELECT htmlRep from 
        (SELECT htmlRep from definition 
        WHERE htmlRep like '%munte%' 
        or htmlRep like '%munți%' 
        or htmlRep like '%muntele%' 
        or htmlRep like '%muntelui%' 
        or htmlRep like '%munții%' 
        or htmlRep like '%munților%') def2 
    WHERE htmlRep like '%cascadă%' 
    or htmlRep like '%cascade%' 
    or htmlRep like '%cascada%' 
    or htmlRep like '%cascadei%' 
    or htmlRep like '%cascadele%' 
    or htmlRep like '%cascadelor%' 
    or htmlRep like '%cascado%') def1 
WHERE htmlRep like '%apă%' 
or htmlRep like '%ape%' 
or htmlRep like '%apa%' 
or htmlRep like '%apei%' 
or htmlRep like '%apele%' 
or htmlRep like '%apelor%' 
or htmlRep like '%apo%'
```

My question is how to optimize this query so it runs much quicker? Is there a way? I'm sure it should be.

PS: I have included the whole query (with all the flexy forms of apa, cascada, munte) so you can see exactly what's going on. I understand that running such a query on a 180.000 records table of around 0,8 GB might take some time, but I'm sure there should be a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would go for a simpler query with '%munt%' for example and then if found, refine the final set. Avoiding `OR` is always good :). You could also just return everything for '%munte%' and filter at client side, so you would save server CPU

Comment: @Sebas: that would be a good idea, but it's not that easy. For you cannot know for sure at which point the flexing starts. For example, for the word **fata** (girl), the dative is **fetei** so it only keeps the **f**. I think most of the definitions contain **f** in their. Another example: **baiat** (boy) has a case in which it becomes **baiete**, and another one **baiatului** so it's kind of irregular. I have all these flex forms in another table.

Answer (score 0):

I just give an idea, not a real answer but the size of comment is too small.
A few years ago, I've had about the same problem with product on a big database. The problem was that depending on location in France, the same product had different name, but not "really different"...
After trying to increase speed, I've decided to work in a completly different way: I put in my database, 2 versions of the data. One which was the "real data" so the name I gave back to the user, and an other which was the one I was looking for. 
Eg, if the user try to find "Good", "GOOD", "gOoD" and so on, you can have "good" in your database and search without taking case in account. But you can also have two entries: "Good" (which would be displayed) and "GOOD" which will be used for searching. When the user enter "Good" of "good" or "GoOD" you change it to GOOD, search and return the other field.
I think in your case, rather than search for: 
munte, munți, muntele, muntelui, munții, munților, searching only for "munt" will be good. In fact rather that having 6 records, you'll have one with "MUNT" as the "search field" and the other declination in other field of the same record.
At return of result, you just will have to continue the test.
Eg: enter muntele, transforme to munt, seach for munt, then test manually muntele with the other field of the munt line.

Sorry if it's not a "real anwser" but just a way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter, but I think, I would have the same problem as described above to **Sebas** comment.